# Can not set visibleRange manually

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to set visibleRange manually, I have start and end in props, and when component loading in React I am trying to

```
calendarRef.current.getApi().view.calendar.setOption('visibleRange', {
            start: formatDate(new Date(from)),
            end: formatDate(new Date(to)),
        });
```

Also was trying to set via props

```
visibleRange={
                    {
                        start: format(new Date(from), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                        end: format(new Date(to), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                    }
                }
```

The problem is that when I click prev/next I send Inertia.visit() to the server and receive events list and dates from/to but the component is fully re-rendered because of SSR (Inertia) and Callendar shows then initial dates because i have needed dates i want to set it to it but not success.
But nothing works
It still shows the range of the current week.
Can someone help me with how I can do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works, i still don't understand what visibleRange do, but to set manually date you have to use 'gotoDate()'
calendarRef.current.getApi().view.calendar.gotoDate(formatDate(new Date(from)));